# Haskell recursive nextWord function

Tags: haskell, recursion

I wanted to implement a function nextWord which given a list of characters `s` (i.e. a `String`)
returns a pair consisiting of the next word in `s` and the remaining characters in `s` after the
first word has been removed. I tried this and I got error messages:

```
nextWord :: String -> (String, String)
nextWord [] = ([],[])
nextWord (next:rest)
    | isSpace next = ([],rest)
    | otherwise    = next : [restWord,restString]
        where
            (restWord,restString) = nextWord next
```

However, when I looked at the solution I noticed that there is a big resemblance:

```
nextWord :: String -> ( String, String )
nextWord [] = ( [], [] )
nextWord ( next : rest )
    | isSpace next = ([], rest)
    | otherwise = let (restWord, restString) = nextWord rest
    in (next : restWord, restString)
```

which works perfectly.

My question is first of all, why didn't my function work? I know I'm doing something wrong when defining `restWord` / `restString`.
Also, in the solution, how does the last line work?

```
next : restWord , restString
```

`restWord`, `restString` isn't a list, therefore how does the cont work here?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, `import Control.Arrow; nextWord = second (drop 1) . break (== ' ')`

Comment: To make clear what user3237465 found out: Your function drops the separating space. I would not expect that by your specification. Also, check out the functions `words` and `unwords` (included in Prelude).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the function you wrote, you sometimes return `([],rest)`, a tuple, and other times return `next : [restWord,restString]`, a list. Those two types are incompatible, and so the function can't be typed.

In the working function, `(next : restWord, restString)` is a tuple: its `fst` is `next:restWord` and its `snd` is `restString`. This way, the function's return value is always a tuple, so the types line up.

Comment: Is there a way of implementing the first function using a where clause like I did?

You're right about the working function. For some reason I was looking at it the wrong way and instead of ((next:restWord),restString) I though it was (next : (restWord,restString))

Comment: Sure, just replace `next : [restWord,restString]` with `(next:restWord, restString)`, and then your definition is identical  to the working one except that it uses `where` instead of `let`.